# Help translating a sentence with オレにあった

Tags: verbs

I'm having trouble translating this sentence (from the manga Banana Fish, if anyone knows that awesome series):

もしオレにあったとしても…
オレはそんなものほしいと思ったことは1度だってない！！

The part I'm having trouble with is オレにあった, I can't figure out which verb あった is supposed to be/what it means...

As for the second part, I think it means something like "I've never wanted something like that, not even once"--but if I'm wrong please correct!

Comment: Would you like to add some context to the question?

Comment: 多分これですよね → http://tweez.net/bananafish_bot/?p=3「”才能がある”とおまえは言ったな オレは普通の人間とは違う――オレには持たざる者の気持ちがわからないと――じゃあおまえはオレの気持ちがわかるのか？ **才能なんて――そんなもの…もしオレにあったとしても…オレはそんなものほしいと思ったことは1度だってない!!** 」

Answer (score 4, accepted):

あった is the past tense form of the verb ある (有る), literally "exists".

「(Somethingが)オレにある」 literally means "(Something) exists in me", "There is (something) in me", i.e. "I have (something)".

「（もし）～～としても」 expresses *hypothetical condition*. "Even if~~"

So 「(～～が)オレにあったとしても」 means "even if I had ~~".

And according to [this page](http://tweez.net/bananafish_bot/?p=3), the whole sentence goes:

> 才能なんて――そんなもの…もしオレにあったとしても…オレはそんなものほしいと思ったことは1度だってない!!

The first half literally says "Talent... even if I had a thing like that..."
→ "Even if I had a talent, ..." "Even if I was talented, ..."

> As for the second part, I think it means something like "I've never wanted something like that, not even once"--but if I'm wrong please correct!

You're correct.